# tinyMCE can't show text effect on web page

Tags: javascript, python, html, tinymce

I create a forum which can leave a message, but how can I show text effect on web page by using tinyMCE?

If I enter **Hello**, it will show `<p><strong>Hello</strong></p>` on the web page.

Here is my code:
[tinymce.init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGDKv.png)
[forum_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAOuz.png)
[forum_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5evXt.png)
Is there anything I have to set up in html or javascript?

I have been stuck with this problem for a long time.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put your "tinyMCE" code, the parts you use, in your question?

Comment: No problem! Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.